# How to make custome popup box in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show popup box above button navigation when user pressed 'beranda' button, it's possible using showdialog? but how can I remove that dark background

[image]

Comment: Please take the [TOUR] and also [read How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Show us some code what you tried.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
showDialog<void>(
      barrierColor: Color(0x01000000),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom pop box like this as a widget easy to use :

```
customAlert() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                height: 150,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(16.0),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text("Add Your Text"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you add an output image ?